# Can not Enable Virtualization in BIOS American Megatrends 1902 version

Tags: bios, virtualization

I am trying to install Linux on my Windows 10 by using WSL but always get the error message 0x80370102. My features, such as Hyper-V, Virtual Machine Platform, Windows Hypervisor Platform, and Windows Subsystem for Linux are all checked in my Windows Features. I also enabled the nested virtualization manually in PowerShell.

After I googled and studied in some websites, I am pretty sure my BIOS virtualization is not enabled. However, when I entered into my BIOS configuration, there is not virtualization setup in my BIOS. There is only one configuration called Intel V-x Technology which is shown as supported. I am not sure if this is virtualization configuration I am looking for. Plus, there is no enable or disable option for this configuration.

I am using BIOS American Megatrends 1902 version. Does anybody know if this BIOS version supports the virtualization?

Comment: So far as I know, just Intel VT-x does not provide full Virtualization in BIOS.

Comment: Support for virtualization depends on your hardware. What CPU / motherboard is this?

Comment: *BIOS American Megatrends 1902 version* says nothing useful. As above, use [edit] to add the relevant information.

Comment: ?????????????   @hyperandey

Comment: You need to disable all of those optional Windows features and simply runt he command to install WSl from the Windows Store. You are looking to enable VT-x within the firmware. The first thing you have to do is figure out, which option enables hardware virtualization, otherwise no matter what you do WSL won;t work.

Comment: Thanks for all your comments. I have tried to disable all the window features one by one to figure out how to enable virtualization. But no luck. I assumed that John's comment is right: Intel VT-x does not provide full virtualization in BIOS. My computer hardware may not allow me to use virtualization.

Comment: That's why we asked about the specs...